# How do I export a Java project on Eclipse as an executable?

Tags: java

I made a Java project with images, external JARs, and natives(the JARs and natives are for LWJGL and Slick). How can I export this as an executable? I already tried JarSplice and WinRun4J, but when I run the executable, nothing happens. Why?

EDIT: There are also sound files and TrueType fonts.

Comment: Not game related...

Answer (score 5):

I like to use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to generate my Java ".exe" files for Windows. You can let the executable auto-download the necessary Java VM if necessary, and, for debug purposes, you can start your executable in console, so if an error happens, you will be able to see what is causing it.

Just remember to ship the extra files with your executable (dlls, images, others)... To create a Windows installer, I recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Comment: I too was an `NSIS` fan. You can also convert `jars` to `exe's` with `NSIS`. See http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Best_Java_Launcher